# heightForRowAtIndexPath is not called after cellForRowAtIndexPath in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, ios8, cell

I have a grouped `UITableView` whose cells' content is dynamic. I need to calculate the actual height I need for each cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. I'm testing in both iOS 7 and iOS 8 devices and I'm finding that in iOS 8 the method `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called when `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` returns (and then, I have cell's height updated), but it is not called in iOS 7 (so all cell's height is always the same).

I wasn't able to find a solution for this problem... please, could somebody help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Your premise is faulty. If you are doing this correctly, then in both iOS 7 and iOS 8 (and in all systems before that, in fact), `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called *before* your call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. In general what happens is that `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called for every row, *before* the first call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. That way, the table has enough information for layout before it starts generating cells.

If you are seeing a difference in behavior, it may be because you are also using the `estimatedRowHeight`, which does behave differently in iOS 8 vs. iOS 7. So the easy solution is: don't do that.